# how to shorten url in codeigniter using .htaccess?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My project url is:

```
localhost/foldername/main(classname)/showmenu(methodname)/different_slugs // (e.g home,aboutus etc)
```

How to short this url to:

```
localhost/foldername/different_slugs //(e.g home,aboutus etc)
```

Comment: You might be referring to `.htaccess` rewriting?? Not sure, it's a little unclear what you are asking.

Comment: actually i want to know how to shorten the url??? Is it possible??

Comment: Anything is possible. I don't know how your web site works, so I can't tell you how to fix it to what you want, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use routing of codeigniter. To know more on routing please click [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.htaccess` for that.

```
RewriteRule ^foldername/main/showmenu/(.*?)/$ localhost/foldername/$1
```

More info can be found [here](http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/)

Comment: @SrrijitaDasgupta How it's not working? Going to `http://localhost/foldername/different_slugs` you can't access what you want or some error?

Comment: the error is shown that page not found   .htaccess file contains Deny from all
^admin/main/showmenu/(.*?)/$ localhost/admin/$1

Comment: please help meeeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 0):

You can use CodeIgniter's router to achieve this. Simply open the `routes.php` file in your `application/config` folder, and add this line:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'main/showmenu';
```

This will redirect anything (and everything) to the specified address.

As for your `.htaccess`, all you need in that is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /foldername/ # in case you're working in a folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js) [NC] # don't process files with these extensions - will be served normally
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] # redirect everything else to index
```